Azure Data Factory (ADF), create a csv dataset that has dynamic file path
I want to create a csv dataset that will pick a file with name that follows a pattern like file_name_ddmmyyyy:
file_name_01012023.csv or file_name_01012024
It d be enough to check if the file name starts with file_name_

I want to extract the metadata of this file and proceed with further validations. Later on, I d like to create a trigger which will trigger the pipeline whenever a file with this filename will arrive in the blob storage container.
I can imagine that the question is: what adf is supposed to do when more than one files having this format will do.
What I can say for now is that, for now, I ll make sure that only one file with this file name pattern will be there

Is your requirement is to trigger the pipeline whenever the file with the above format uploaded? Also, you said that you will make sure there will be only one file with that pattern right?

Now, im in the testing phase so I usually trigger it manually but later the pipeline should be executed using a trigger. Also yes, for now I manually make sure that there is only one file there

Is your source a storage account?

Yeap the source is a storage account

You can use storage event trigger in ADF for this requirement.
First create two string type parameters in the pipeline parameters section and don't give any default values to those.
Next Go to triggers -> new and create trigger like below.

You can check all containers if you want.
Then, pass the trigger parameters @triggerBody().folderPath and @triggerBody().fileName to the created pipeline parameters.

This trigger will trigger the pipeline whenever a file with the pattern of file_name*.csv is uploaded or modified.
To make sure the triggered file is of correct pattern, use if activity in the pipeline with below expression.
@and(equals(length(split(split(pipeline().parameters.filename,'_')[2],'.')[0]),8),contains(split(split(pipeline().parameters.filename,'_')[2],'.')[0],'20'))


Inside True activities of If, use your activities to use the file. To get the file path dynamically in the dataset, you can use dataset parameters. In the dataset, create a string parameter in the parameters section without any value.
In the dynamic expression of file name use that parameter @dataset().<parameter_name>.

In your activity, when you use dataset, it will ask to provide value to this parameter. Then you can give below expression to that.
@concat(pipeline().parameters.folderpath,'/',pipeline().parameters.filename)


For sample, I have used lookup, you can use copy activity or other as per your requirement.

Thanks a lot for your answer! Let me test it and I ll accept it

I haven't fully understood the usage of @triggerBody().fileName and @triggerBody().folderPath. Where do they come from and how do they get populated?

Those are the trigger parameters by default which will have trigger file folder path and file name. You cannot use those directly in the pipeline. You can only pass those to any pipeline parameters and use pipeline parameters in the pipeline. That's why I have created pipeline parameters and passed trigger parameter values to those. If there is any need of using triggered file path in the pipeline, you can use these parameters.

You can check this doc to know more about storage event triggers in ADF.

I followed the instructions: it seems that the trigger and pipeline params work as expected (I used a set variable activity which creates a variable with the value some_container/file_name_01012023.csv) but dataset/get_metadata activity refuses to extract the metadata of the file for some reason. Did it work for you? (for the record I upload the file_name_01012023.csv in the some_container container )

Let me check and update the answer if required.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It works as expected! Thanks a lot! Valuable input

Good to hear, that it worked for you : ).
